# Corrupted TFrecord

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

I've converted MNIST to TFRecords. I validated that the records are of valid format using this code:

```
example.ParseFromString(raw_record.numpy())
print(example)
```

Output:

```
features {
  feature {
    key: "depth"
    value {
      int64_list {
        value: 1
      }
    }
  }
...
```

I then use the TFRecordDataset to read and parse the files using map function:

```
def parse(record):
        feature = {
            'height': tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.int64, allow_missing=True),
            'width': tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.int64, allow_missing=True),
            'depth': tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.int64, allow_missing=True),
            'label': tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.int64, allow_missing=True),
            'image_raw': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
        }
    features = tf.io.parse_single_example(record, feature)

    image = tf.io.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
    image.set_shape([28 * 28])
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) * (1. / 255) - 0.5
    image = tf.reshape(image, [28, 28, 1])

    label = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int32)

    return image, label

BATCH_SIZE = 64 * 10
NUM_PARALLEL_BATCHES = 2
LOCAL_PATTERN = './data/*'
ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(LOCAL_PATTERN)
ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=ds) \
    .map(parse) \
    .batch(batch_size=NUM_PARALLEL_BATCHES)
```

This results in an error:

> File
> "/Users/Projects/mobileye/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py",
> line 60, in quick_execute
> inputs, attrs, num_outputs) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError:  corrupted
> record at 0    [[node IteratorGetNext (defined at
> cnn_mnist_pipe_gcp.py:94) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_885]

EDIT: The code for writing the tfrecords:

```
  with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(filename) as writer:
      image_raw = images[index].tostring()
      example = tf.train.Example(
          features=tf.train.Features(
              feature={
                  'height': _int64_feature(rows),
                  'width': _int64_feature(cols),
                  'depth': _int64_feature(depth),
                  'label': _int64_feature(int(labels[index])),
                  'image_raw': _bytes_feature(image_raw)
              }))
      writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for writing tfrecords as well?

Comment: @JY2k Were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue when I tried to train `efficientDet-object-detection` model, from exported dataset from Roboflow as `tfrecord` files. Here's how I solve this:

This error means your generated `tfrecord` files are corrupted. Use the following script to check the state of the `tfrecord` files:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def is_tfrecord_corrupted(tfrecord_file):
    try:
        for record in tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecord_file):
            # Attempt to parse the record
            _ = tf.train.Example.FromString(record.numpy())
    except tf.errors.DataLossError as e:
        print(f"DataLossError encountered: {e}")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return True
    return False

# Replace with your TFRecord file paths 
tfrecord_files = ['your_test_record_fname', 'your_train_record_fname']

for tfrecord_file in tfrecord_files:
  if is_tfrecord_corrupted(tfrecord_file):
      print(f"The TFRecord file {tfrecord_file} is corrupted.")
  else:
      print(f"The TFRecord file {tfrecord_file} is fine.")
```

To fix the corrupted `tfrecords`, I exported the datasets as `pascal-voc` format, and then I wrote the following script hosted here on GitHub to generate new `tfrecords` from the `pascal-voc` formatted dataset.

##### Script to generate new `tfrecords` is here: https://github.com/arrafi-musabbir/license-plate-detection-recognition/blob/main/generate_tfrecord.py

- Create your own `label-map-pbtxt` according to your dataset:

```
label_path = "your label_map.pbtxt path"

# modify according to your dataset class names
labels = [{'name':'license', 'id':1}]

with open(label_path, 'w') as f:
    for label in labels:
        f.write('item { \n')
        f.write('\tname:\'{}\'\n'.format(label['name']))
        f.write('\tid:{}\n'.format(label['id']))
        f.write('}\n')
```

- Run the script as the following:

```
python generate_tfrecord.py -x {train_dir_path} -l {labelmap_path} -o {new_train_record_path}
python generate_tfrecord.py -x {valid_dir_path} -l {labelmap_path} -o {new_valid_record_path}
python generate_tfrecord.py -x {test_dir_path} -l {labelmap_path} -o {new_test_record_path}
```

Afterwards, run the `is_tfrecord_corrupted(tfrecord_file)` again and you will see that the `tfrecords` are fine.

[image]